Find partial word and return value in adjacent cell
I have a list of 10 words in table for each word ther wil be a code.
There are many rows which are in scentence form. Now I need if any of my table words contains in cell it should return a value of the word code in the currentrow of the next colm.
Example..my words and code
1.Apple - App 
2.Orange - org 
3.Mysore- mys

Sentence example... In A columns
1.This is an apple
2.My native mysore
3.I like orange

Now I need codes return in column B in same row.
Is that possible in VBA. Please anyone help me on this
I tried VLookup, but it works only for exact matches. Now I'm working on VBE. Can anyone help with the code

Please post the code you have attempted thusfar.  Yes, this is possible, and in many different ways; knowing your specific approach and helping correct the particular issue with your code would be where the conversation can begin.

This is also possible with formulas btw.

Something like this, maybe?

You can use this formula which has to be entered with ctrl+shift+enter if you don't work with Office 365 or Excel for the web.
=INDEX($F$1:$F$3,MATCH(TRUE,ISNUMBER(SEARCH($E$1:$E$3,A1)),0))




Use a Dictionary object to store the map table

Microsoft documentation:

InStr function


Range.Resize property (Excel)


Range.CurrentRegion property (Excel)

Option Explicit
Sub Demo()
    Dim objDic As Object, rngData As Range
    Dim i As Long, sKey
    Dim arrData
    Const CELL_MAP = "E1" ' top-left cell of map table
    Const CELL_DATA = "A1" ' top-left cell of data table
    Set objDic = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    Set rngData = Range(CELL_MAP).CurrentRegion
    arrData = rngData.Value
    For i = LBound(arrData) To UBound(arrData)
        objDic(arrData(i, 1)) = arrData(i, 2)
    Next i
    Set rngData = Range(CELL_DATA).CurrentRegion.Resize(, 2)
    arrData = rngData.Value
    For i = LBound(arrData) To UBound(arrData)
        For Each sKey In objDic.keys
            If InStr(1, arrData(i, 1), sKey, vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
                arrData(i, 2) = objDic(sKey)
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
    Next i
    rngData = arrData
End Sub


